# How to read path from another method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method which unzips file from my method, and I have a separate method which I want to create so it can read the unzip files and load them as needed.

```
    private string UnzipFiles()
    {
        Chilkat.Zip zip = new Chilkat.Zip();
        string zippedFilePath = @"C:\Users\TestData";
        string unzippedFilePath = @"C:\Users\Temp";

        bool success = zip.UnlockComponent("LIVECOZIP_3BzssvnbmYxp");

        if (!success)
        {
            string errorMsg = zip.LastErrorText;
            Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
            return errorMsg;
        }

        string[] newzip = (Directory.GetFiles(zippedFilePath));

        foreach (string file in newzip)
        {
            success = zip.OpenZip(file);
            {
                Console.WriteLine(zip.LastErrorText);

            }
            zip.DecryptPassword = "hANhvU8MX7iq0f2M";
            int unzipCount;

            unzipCount = zip.Unzip(unzippedFilePath);
            if (unzipCount < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("unzipping file");
            }
        }
        return unzippedFilePath;
```

**The method below is where I need help. I want to call the method above and be able to read each file. Right now I am getting error.**

```
   public void LoadNewFile()
    {
        UnzipFiles();

         foreach (String file in UnzipFiles) 
         //How to call each file?
         {
           userSelectedFilePath += file + Environment.NewLine;
           names_of_files.Add(file);
         }
```

Comment: You can refactor unzip method to be a `IDisposable` class, then wrapping it into `using` let you access its temporal (for unzip duration) values (as public properties).

Comment: Is that my only option? just wondering

Comment: What is the error being reported?  From the above code at first glance it appears you are trying to do a foreach on a method?

Comment: *"Is that my only option? just wondering "* - of course not, you can use current type members (fields/properties) or return values (Tuple, custom type, ref/out parameters). `using` + `IDisposable` is simply more clean as you are calling `UnzipFiles` anyway.

Comment: Do you just want `LoadNewFile()` to have a list of all the files that `UnzipFiles()` created? If that's the case, `UnzipFiles()` should return `List<string>` instead of `String`. It should return a list of all the files it created. Then `LoadNewFIle` would delete the first call to `UnzipFiles()`, and the loop would call `UnzipFiles()` instead: `foreach (string file in UnzipFiles()) { ... }`

Comment: David Setty, that is correct and I really just need to access the Zip and unzip path from above method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var path = UnzipFiles();
var unZippedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (var file in unZippedFiles)
{
 //tratata
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to change `UnzipFiles` to return a List of strings.  Something like this:

```
private List<string> UnzipFiles()
{
    Chilkat.Zip zip = new Chilkat.Zip();
    string zippedFilePath = @"C:\Users\TestData";
    string unzippedFilePath = @"C:\Users\Temp";
    var unzippedFileList = new List<string>();

    bool success = zip.UnlockComponent("LIVECOZIP_3BzssvnbmYxp");

    if (!success)
    {
        string errorMsg = zip.LastErrorText;
        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
        return errorMsg;
    }

    string[] newzip = (Directory.GetFiles(zippedFilePath));

    foreach (string file in newzip)
    {
        unzippedFileList.Add(file);
        success = zip.OpenZip(file);
        {
            Console.WriteLine(zip.LastErrorText);

        }
        zip.DecryptPassword = "hANhvU8MX7iq0f2M";
        int unzipCount;

        unzipCount = zip.Unzip(unzippedFilePath);
        if (unzipCount < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unzipping file");
        }
    }

    return unzippedFileList;
}
```

Comment: Getting this error on the "return". An object of a type convertible to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' is required.